# Update the SelectOneMenu in all pages using template

Tags: jsf, primefaces

my problem is that I use a template in pages. This template has a SelectOneMenu. I want to actualize the new selection value in all pages using this template. It should be the same component. Do I need websockets for this or is it possible to actualize the selection of this selectOneMenu without websockets (event-based communication).

My code snippet:

```
<h:form prependId="false" id="masterTemplateForm">
        <p:menubar style="align">
            <p:menuitem value="Tab1">
            </p:menuitem>

            <p:menuitem value="Tab2">

            </p:menuitem>

            <p:menuitem value="Tab3">

            </p:menuitem>
            <f:facet name="options">
                <ui:insert name="tabTitle" />
                <p:outputLabel value="Benutzer: " />
                <p:selectOneMenu style="vertical-align:middle;" id="userSelect"
                    value="#{masterTemplateController.actualUser}"
                    converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsIndexConverter">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Benutzer auswählen --" itemValue="#{null}" />
                    <f:selectItems var="currentUser"
                        value="#{masterTemplateController.findAllUser()}"
                        itemLabel="#{currentUser.benutzerName}" itemValue="#{currentUser}" />
                    <p:ajax update="userSelect" event="change" listener="#{masterTemplateController.selectUserHandler}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
        </p:menubar>
    </h:form>
    <ui:insert name="bodyContent" />
```

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: please be more specific give more detail to understand your need

Comment: _"Do I need websockets"_: yes

Comment: @YagamiLight What I understood is that this selectOneMenu component has an id which should be sufficient for identification. I have different Pages which are using this template. The selection of a new value should also be updated and shown in the opened pages which are using this template.

Comment: @Kukeltje Even if I don't want to update all clients but just my session ?

Comment: multiple open pages of one user?: yes

Comment: @Kukeltje Ok. I just had this selectOneMenu as a placeholder which is representing different users, for any future security / login implementation...

Comment: What Kukeltje want to say (and it's true) it can be one open active page for the user and changes can be applied if you don't refresh the page

Comment: @YagamiLight Aye got that. So the solution is just implementing a refresh button on the other pages which performs the selection of the new value? Or polling...

Comment: yes it can be a solution the thing is for example if you are working in an accounting app the data that you show is something important you need to check the data version tell me if you need more informations